# Save Uri of selected Tone

Tags: android

i try to save the selected ringtone like this :

```
setSoundBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
                            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
                            tmp = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
                        }
                    });
```

Tmp is a `Uri` and when i create the notification , i call

```
.setSound(tmp)
```

Actually this doesnt work, but when i change this to :

```
.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
```

I can hear the sound.
Maybe someone can help me out with this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is write but for getting the uri of selected ringtone you have to implement onActivityResult in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 5: 
          tmp = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now check intent is the object of Intent which is defined in onActivityResult